# Как у него выходит результат в( prestashop ) через двойной foreach?

Tags: php

```
foreach ($products as $kp => $p)
        foreach ($grades_comments as $gc)
          if ($gc['id_product'] == $p['id_product'])
          {
            $products[$kp]['mymodcomments']['grade_avg'] = round($gc['grade_avg']);
            $products[$kp]['mymodcomments']['nb_comments'] = $gc['nb_comments'];
          }
      $find['result'] = $products;
```

я так понимал раньше что (на этом примере)

foreach ($products as $kp => $p)

```
foreach ($p['подмассив'] as $gc)
```

и таким образом вытянуть данные....

Comment: Ваш вопрос заключается в чем?

Comment: как оно работает,как образом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос вы поставили довольно сложно. Да и сокращённый синтаксис `foreach` сбивает с толку. А работает это примерно следующим образом:

```
Первый цикл пробегает по массиву продуктов $products и в каждой итерации:
    1) Присваивает значение элемента массива переменной $p, а имя ключа переменной $kp;
    2) Пробегает по массиву оценок $grades_comments и в каждой итерации:
        2.1) Присваивает значение элемента массива переменной $gc;
        2.2) Проверяет, совпадает ли идентификатор продукта в массиве оценок с
             идентификатором продукта в массиве продуктов. Если совпадает, то в текущий
             элемент массива продуктов из первого цикла добавляется пара значений
             из текущего элемента массива оценок из второго цикла;
        2.3) значение обновленного массива $products присваевается переменной
             $find['result'].
```

Дальше вы сами разбирайтесь, опираясь на полный текст скрипта.

Comment: никогда  не видел такой реализации. Спасибовам большое.  Вопрос уже более простой  можно ли такое использовать ,оценят ли коллектив ?

Comment: @msim если это работает, то почему бы и нет? Хотя от сокращённого синтаксиса я бы отказался в пользу читабельности.